# combining 5 arrays with php based on keys

Tags: php

I have 5 arrays like this

```
print_r($_POST['ponumber']);
print_r($_POST['man_part_number']);
print_r($_POST['model']);
print_r($_POST['damaged']);
print_r($_POST['serial_number']);
print_r($_POST['skid']);
```

which produces

```
Array
(
    [0] => 111111
    [1] => 111111
    [2] => 111111
    [3] => 111111
)
Array
(
    [0] => 11C2555
    [1] => 11C2555
    [2] => 11C2555
    [3] => 11C2555
)
Array
(
    [0] => FORMS PRINTER 2500 SERIES
    [1] => FORMS PRINTER 2500 SERIES
    [2] => FORMS PRINTER 2500 SERIES
    [3] => FORMS PRINTER 2500 SERIES
)
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 0
)
Array
(
    [0] => CNCQ202070
    [1] => CNCQ210800
    [2] => MY5203B1KQ
    [3] => CN1863Q0PQ
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 1
)
```

I need to combine them based on keys so that I get 4 arrays total that look like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => 111111
    [1] => 11C2555
    [2] => FORMS PRINTER 2500 SERIES
    [3] => 0
    [4] => CNCQ202070
 )
```

and so on...

It needs to match each key in each array and combine them into one array. I was trying array_combine and array_merge but I don't think that was the right way to go. Anyone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$items = array();

for($x = 0; $x < count($_POST['ponumber']); $x++){
    $item = array($_POST['ponumber']);
    $item[] = $_POST['ponumber'][$x];
    $item[] = $_POST['man_part_number'][$x];
    $item[] = $_POST['model'][$x];
    $item[] = $_POST['damaged'][$x];
    $item[] = $_POST['serial_number'][$x];
    $item[] = $_POST['skid'][$x];
    $items[] = $item;
}
```

Will give an array of the arrays you need. Note that this assumes that all arrays are the same size. You may need to add some checks if this is not the case.

Comment: Warning:  count() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given

Comment: @CesarBielich Whoops, typo. Fixed.

Comment: your code worked except I had to change "$item = array($_POST['ponumber']);" to "$item = array();" Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a nested foreach loop to make five new arrays?

Granted it is long and tedious but it could be a start if you need it in a rush?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
$counter = 0;
$temp = array();
 if(isset($_POST)){ // check if $_POST isset.

foreach($_POST as $key=>$myarr)
    {
       foreach($myarr as $k=>$value)
       {

          $temp[$counter] = $value;
          break;
       }
       $counter++;
    }
    }
```

to check out you can do:

```
var_dump($temp);
```

*Hope that I helped*

Comment: Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() line 5

Comment: what error... I've tested it just now. can you tell me what is your error??

Comment: @CesarBielich, do you mean the first foreach or the second one? line 5 on your device differs from here.

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/content/createserialnumbertemplist.php on line 5. Its line 5 of your code "foreach($myarr as $k=>$value)"

Comment: take a look at my edit. and try it. I added isset for the POST to check first. @CesarBielich

Comment: @CesarBielich, please feedback ?? I'm curios about why it's not working with you!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you can structure the form as such, you'll get a more friendly `$_POST` array:

```
<form>
  <input name="data[0][ponumber]" />
  <input name="data[0][man_part_number]" />
  <input name="data[0][model]" />
  <input name="data[0][damaged]" />
  <input name="data[0][serial_number]" />
  <input name="data[0][skid]" />

  <input name="data[1][ponumber]" />
  <input name="data[1][man_part_number]" />
  <input name="data[1][model]" />
  <input name="data[1][damaged]" />
  <input name="data[1][serial_number]" />
  <input name="data[1][skid]" />
</form>
```

`$_POST` will look like:

```
'data' => array(
  0 => array(
    'ponumber' => '111111',
    'man_part_number' => '11C2555',
    'model' => 'FORMS PRINTER 2500 SERIES',
    'damaged' => '0',
    'serial_number' => 'CNCQ202070',
    'skid' => '1',
  ), ...
)
```